# RTSP vlc player stream delay issue in react native

Tags: react-native, vlc, rtsp

I am working on an app in which in needed to use a media player that supports rtsp streaming so i installed [react-native-vlc-media-player](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-vlc-media-player) library. so after assigning the url according to documentation the stream is playing and i made buttons to change the directions of the camera after hitting the api i get response instantly but on vlc player it has a delay of approximately 15 to 18s to update the video.
Here is the code:

```js
   <VLCPlayer
                style={style.imageStyle}
                videoAspectRatio="16:9"
                source={{ uri: videoUrl }}
                onError={(err) => console.log("video error:", err)}
                onPaused={isPaused}
                repeat={true}
                mediaOptions={{
                  ":network-caching": 150,
                  ":live-caching": 0,
                  ":file-caching": 0,
                  ":live-caching": 0,
                  ":network-caching": 150,
                  ":clock-jitter": 0,
                  ":clock-synchro": 0,
                }}
                initType={2}
                initOptions={["--no-audio", "--no-stats", "--rtsp-tcp"]}
              />
```

Any suggestion how can i reduce or remove the delay in vlc player

Comment: Hello, did you find a solution ? I think `react-native-vlc-media-player` is not maintainable @Aliyan

Comment: Hi, No I didn't find any solution yet. Yes that's the issue these libraries doesn't have much maintenance for rtsp streaming in react-native. Any suggestion ? I can change the library then.

Comment: I have the same problem, i am thinking using WebRTC with rtsp but i don't know if this gonna work. @Aliyan

Comment: Oh ok, if you find any solution then, kindly let me know, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `":live-caching": 0,` parameter to 150 or 300.
It's possible that because of 0 buffer size it doesn't accumulate enough data to start decoding.

Comment: Still same issue, I think it is react native vlc library causing the issue so any other library suggestion ? or any idea to resolve this within this library